# Spherical functions which are invariant under a finite rotation group

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, rotations, symmetry, spherical-harmonics

Is there a nice, clean reference which lists a basis in terms of (linear combinations of) spherical harmonics for the $L^2$ space of functions defined on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ which are invariant under the action of a finite subgroup of $SO(3)$ ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One can find a spanning subset by applying the operator $\sum_{g\in G}g$ to a basis. Then I guess you need to figure out linear dependencies. Not sure if this is helpful.